# Calling Generic WebAPI end point from the code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint as shown here in my API controller:

```
[HttpPost("getdynamictypedbytasync")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDynamicTypedByTAsync<T>([FromBody] object[] datas) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        var data = await UowLookups.DynamicRepository().GetAllAsyncByT<T>();
        return Ok(data);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is this the right method?
2. How will I call this API from an ASP.NET MVC app and pass some parameters?

I tried this code, but I get errors:

```
Type type = typeof(T);
var property = type.GetProperties();

using (var response = await _httpGatewayClient.PostAsJsonAsync(apiEndpoint, type, _options))
```

Comment: Have you tried calling it from browser/postman? =)

Comment: Why don't you try with dynamic which can handle any kind of parameter for instance you can try like this `public async Task<IActionResult> GetDynamicTypedByTAsync([FromBody] dynamic datas)`. However, if you would like to handle only dynamic formdata `IFormCollection` would be ideal option for you.

Comment: Hello Farid, Thankyou for the quick response. Let me try to do that, but i have another problem. The object passed to the API is further send to a generic repository. Can you help me in doing that. Current code is ```var data = await UowLookups.DynamicRepository().GetAllAsyncByT<T>();``` I want to pass the "dynamic datas" suggested by you as <T> here.